# Как сделать Hint у TrayIcon в Delphi длиной больше 127 символов?

Tags: delphi, winapi, icon, hint

Подскажите компоненту или метод сделать Hint у TrayIcon в Delphi длиной больше 127 символов.

Нужен именно Hint (подсказка), не BaloonHint.

Желательно чтобы способ был применим к стандартной TrayIcon или какой то компонент аналог TrayIcon, но с более длинным Hint.

Желательно чтобы компонент поддерживал HTML

Answer (score 3):

Опираясь на ограничение вопроса:

> Нужен именно Hint (подсказка), не BaloonHint.

[Официальная документация WinAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataw#members) гласит:

> **szTip** For Windows 2000 and later, szTip can have a maximum of 128 characters, including the terminating null character.

То есть - это ограничение самой операционной системы и ни один компонент, использующий *штатный механизм показа* хинта (не баллуна), не преодолеет его при всём желании.

P.S. показ штатного баллуна ограничен 256 символами, включая терминальный 0.

Comment: А есть может быть какие то компоненты которые реализуют свой Hint ? Без ограничения по длине ?

Comment: @ВладимирГерасимюк возможно, но маловероятно - слишком специфическая задача. Попробуйте посмотреть, например, на https://torry.net/pages.php?id=245 или гитхабе.